# Ribbon interface for GTK and Qt

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, gtk, ribbon

Is it possible to implement ribbon interface in Windows7 in GTK or Qt? If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, some libraries for Ribbon widgets have already been released.

[image: Ribbon widget it GTK#]

<sub>see [this](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2007/Aug-30-1.html) post and [this](http://qiacat.blogspot.com/2009/04/ribbon-ui-korat-ui.html) one.</sub>

There is also [QtitanRibbon](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4214), an implementation of Microsoft's Ribbon UI for QT.

[image: Qtitan Ribbon]

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep to vote or comment, but @Daniele Lupo's comment about needing to sign an agreement isn't quite true. There is enough prior art floating around that suggests Microsoft won't be awarded the patent.

Source: [Ribbon (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing))

Answer (score 1):

Take care that, on order to use a ribbon, you must accept the [Office UI Licensing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/aa973809.aspx) (see part 3) even if you don't use its libraries but creates your own that re-create the same look&feel, because they have some patent about this interface. If you accept it, you have no problem in its implementation, otherwise I don't know.